# Travis CI showing an old build instead the last one

Tags: travis-ci

The last commit was built successfully, but Travis CI is showing an old build that failed.

- [The "current" build (#6)](https://travis-ci.org/jorgebg/falaciaslogicas.com)
- [The last build (#7)](https://travis-ci.org/jorgebg/falaciaslogicas.com/builds)

So the status of the repository is red instead green.

Why is Travis CI selecting my #6 build as the "current" instead the last one (#7)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is probably a question for Travis CI support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted with [@banzaiman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136333/banzaiman) through IRC #travis channel he gave me the solution:

> It's showing your `0.2.3` tag instead of the `0.2.4` tag [...] because build `#53859240` (`0.2.3`) finished after `#53884768` (`0.2.4`).
>
> **The last one chronologically overwrites the result**. I know this is not intuitive, but that's how it works right now.
>
> **Rerun the last commit job** `#7` (`0.2.4`), and it should turn green.

Answer (score 0):

It must be something about the Travis CI page, it is generating the status image for the "current build" page with `?branch=0.2.3`. If you import the status image:

[image: Build Status]

You will see that is passing.
You should contact TravisCI support for more info on the page behavior.

Comment: Ok thank you, I have sent them an email with a link to this question, let's wait for they response ^^